# Detect when slick slider initialises

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I'm trying to fire some code when [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) initializes. Apparently in the newest version 1.4 "callback methods have been deprecated and replaced with events."

This doesn't work for me though:

```
$('.spv-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    console.log("initialised")
});
```

what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I'm not sure at which point you tried to initialize slickslider, but you have to do it **after** binding the `init` event.

So write your piece of code as you did and after that initialize the slider:

```
$('.spv-slider').on('init', function(event, slick){
    console.log("initialized")
});
```

And then:

```
$('.spv-slider').slick();
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to fire after the slider is initialised. I am trying to fire the `slickNext` event on init, but I get the error `Cannot read property 'slickNext' of undefined`... That being said, the answer is correct in that the init event must be written before the slick function.