# Equal Height Bootstrap Cards within Slick Carousel

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, slick.js

I'm having trouble obtaining equal height bootstrap cards with differing length body content with a slick carousel. I've looked at similar answers on here and none of them appear to work in my scenario.

I've managed get equal height slides but for some reason I cannot get the cards within the slides to be 100% height of the slide (parent container). I'm trying to achieve what the Bootstrap class 'card-deck' achieves but in a carousel.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10 mx-auto s_container">
                <div class="slider">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates, rem?</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, quasi soluta dolorum pariatur hic porro.</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto magnam esse molestiae est. Nisi aliquam libero dolorem? Qui, enim nam.</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Voluptates, rem?</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, quasi soluta dolorum pariatur hic porro.</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="img-ph.jpg" alt="place holder">
                        <div class="card-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iusto magnam esse molestiae est. Nisi aliquam libero dolorem? Qui, enim nam.</div>
                        <div class="card-footer">
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">More Info</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.s_container{
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 40px 0 40px;
width: 100%;
}

.slider{
border: 2px solid red;
}

.slick-track {
display: flex !important;
}

.slick-slide{
margin: 12px;
height: auto;
border: 2px solid green;
}

.slick-frame {
visibility: hidden;
}
```

An example of running can be found here:

[Example](https://codepen.io/Fluxtor/pen/pGKNYY)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Equal height has been a problem for a lot of developers over the years.
In my opinion you can choose between 2 different solutions:

1. Javascript solution

You loop over all the cards and save the biggest height. Set all cards to this height with JS after biggest one has been defined.

https://www.bootply.com/LnwZjxWe7L

```
// Get cards
var cards = $('.card-body');
var maxHeight = 0;

// Loop all cards and check height, if bigger than max then save it
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  if (maxHeight < $(cards[i]).outerHeight()) {
    maxHeight = $(cards[i]).outerHeight();
  }
}
// Set ALL card bodies to this height
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  $(cards[i]).height(maxHeight);
}
```

2. CSS only solution

This one is a bit more complex to explain so here is an example how to do it:

```css
#container3 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:green;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
#container2 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:yellow;
    position:relative;
    right:30%;
}
#container1 {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    background:red;
    position:relative;
    right:40%;
}
#col1 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:72%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col2 {
    float:left;
    width:36%;
    position:relative;
    left:76%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#col3 {
    float:left;
    width:26%;
    position:relative;
    left:80%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="container3"> <!-- added -->
    <div id="container2"> <!-- added -->
        <div id="container1">
            <div id="col1">Column 1</div>
            <div id="col2">Column 2</div>
            <div id="col3">Super long text! Wow looks at this text, it is so long it needs to break on multiple lines!</div>
        </div>
    </div> <!-- added -->
</div> <!-- added -->
```

I got this solution from here:
https://matthewjamestaylor.com/equal-height-columns

Comment: Not sure either of these solutions would work with Bootstrap cards. The cards I'm using are made up of image,body and footer divs. The variable length is only within the card-body so this is the only part which needs to grow. Bootstrap has a built in wrapper which allows the card body to grow leaving white space after the shorter text. So basically the card footers are always aligned at the lowest point. I do appreciate your answer and the fact that it might be my lack of understanding

Comment: I forked your codepen to show you how it works : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bzjgBx

Comment: Fantastic. I was referring to the css solution but this JS solution you forked is exactly what I'm after, thank you!

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this but I have one other issue which is me and not a problem with your solution. Not sure if you are familiar with slick or not but currently I'm struggling with where to call your code from in my page. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I worked with slick before but that is a while ago. But I suppose you should call the function when the slider is initialised. Check this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28236840/detect-when-slick-slider-initialises

Comment: I tried that but doesn't seem to work. I'll have another look!