# Bootstrap cards with the same height and responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I developed a grid with three columns (2 equal and one smaller).
My problem is that I can't set a height on the cards, I used them in px and it worked, but it's not the best way. I expect that the three columns have the same height (100% of the page) and some of the cards occupy 75%, 50%, 25% 20% of the page.

Is there a way to define a fully responsive height without using px?

Thanks !

**CODE**

```
 <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card card1">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">With supporting .</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card card1">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">With supporting .</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card card1">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">With supporting .</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card card1">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">With supporting .</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: have you tried set height as % value? or you can set height as vh value

Comment: @gnujoow Yes, I tested it, but the height doesn't work. They increase the height if you increase the height of the row, but I think that is not the best solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal Height Bootstrap Cards within Slick Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653060/equal-height-bootstrap-cards-within-slick-carousel)

Comment: @Wimanicesir 
I tried using this solution but it didn't work, I can't set the height of the cards in % :(

Answer (score 3):

use the class d-flex as mentioned below. It will give you the same height for all the 4 cards.

```
<div class="col-3 d-flex">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col">
     <div class="card card2">
       <div class="card-body">
         <p class="card-text">50% height</p>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card card2">
        <div class="card-body">
          <p class="card-text">50% height</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col d-flex">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="card card3">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text">25% height</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card card4">
              <div class="card-body">
                <p class="card-text">75% height</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay with it being 50% of the screen height, you could use "vh".

The following CSS worked in your code pen:

> .card2 .card-body{
>        height: 50vh;
>   }