# Place the three columns with the same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Using the bootstrap I created three columns. Within each column I have several rows.

My problem is that the columns are not the same height, the left column is bigger than the rest, they were supposed to all be the same height.

In the cards I did not define any height, that is, if any of the columns increased the height, the rest would follow this growth automatically in order to have all the same height.

Is there a way to place all the columns at the same height without using measurements in pixels (px)?

Thanks

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="col-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
      <div class="card cardm">
        <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
      <div class="card cardm">
        <div class="card-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card cardm">
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="card cardm">
        <div class="card-body">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal Height Bootstrap Cards within Slick Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653060/equal-height-bootstrap-cards-within-slick-carousel)

Comment: @Wimanicesir Thanks for the reply, 
I tried something like this, I didn't get what I wanted :(

Comment: *only* columns (`col`) should be contained inside `row`.. not `card`

Comment: @Wimanicesir 
I don't want the height of the cards equal, I want the 3 columns with equal height

Comment: your columns are already eqaul in height

Comment: @TemaniAfif 
The column may even be, but the lines do not completely fill the column

Comment: so you need to adjust your question to be more clear. You don't want the column to be equal in height but the content to fill all the height.

Comment: @TemaniAfif In the image I express this better. I want my last line to finish at the same time as the rest. Right now I have one ending at the end and the others ending almost at the beginning, they should all end at the end

Comment: you said : *My problem is that the columns are not the same height,*

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/prak_mtl/ta3spmgu/3/
Check this JS fiddle and let me know if this is what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `Bootstrap4` then you can easily `achieve by BS4 predefined classes` like `h-100` and also your html structure is not correct way so follow as per bootstrap instructions.
`Predefined classes for width & height follow:` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/sizing/#relative-to-the-parent

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container my-2">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card cardm h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card cardm h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card cardm h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          Laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="col-3">
      <div class="card cardm h-100">
        <div class="card-body">
          Voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Done with js, just copied from the duplicate linked post. Shows weird on a small screen though.

```js
// Get cards
var cards = $('.card');
var maxHeight = 0;

// Loop all cards and check height, if bigger than max then save it
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  if (maxHeight < $(cards[i]).outerHeight()) {
    maxHeight = $(cards[i]).outerHeight();
  }
}
// Set ALL card bodies to this height
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  $(cards[i]).height(maxHeight);
}
```

```css
.mycontainer {
    width: 96%;
    margin-top: 148px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.card{
    width:100%;
    margin-top:15px;
    background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 20px #BCBCCB47;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 100%;height: 100%; overflow-y: auto; overflow-x: hidden;">
    <div class="row mycontainer">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body" style="padding: 8px;">
            
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
               
            
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="card" style="margin-left:15px">
                <div class="card-body">
               
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="card" style="margin-left:15px">
                <div class="card-body">
           
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
         
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="card" style="margin-left:15px">
                <div class="card-body">
           
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
                <div class="card cardm">
                  <div class="card-body">
                 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
                <div class="card cardm">
                  <div class="card-body">
                
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
                <div class="card cardm">
                  <div class="card-body">
                 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
                <div class="card cardm">
                  <div class="card-body">
                 
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="row h-100">
              <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body" style="padding: 16px;">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
            <div class="card cardm">
              <div class="card-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col" style="padding-right:0">
            <div class="card cardm">
              <div class="card-body">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card cardm">
              <div class="card-body">
             
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col">
            <div class="card cardm">
              <div class="card-body">
           
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want the height of the cards equal, I want the 3 columns with equal height

Comment: Right, the biggest card in the row , decides her height. Thanks for the help !

Comment: It was not me :(

Comment: I know that you didin't downvote, but I guess you didn't upvote as well because it would be zero :)