# Is it possible to dynamically set height for rows based on the biggest value of 100% height of one of them?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a grid and some of the dynamically rendered components have different amount of text in children components so if I set height of those text elements to 100%, some cells would be different height size. Is there a way to check the longest text element, take its innerHeight and then set it as a fixed height for the rest of the cells in a row?

https://jsfiddle.net/3m7L0ok6/1/

Some code for context:

```css
.parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.child1,
child2 {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<cell>
  <div className='parent'>
    <div className='child1'>{name}</div>
    <span className='child2'>{longname}</span>
  </div>
</cell>
```

Comment: Do you mean a grid using css grid or a tablet element? Could you share some image or codesandbox?

Comment: With CSS you should consider Flex. You could always use a JS script that detects the biggest size and set this to all children.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/uvir8f  Not my project, but this website has the same problem. Look at how the cards are different size due to the content inside being different

Comment: @Wimanicesir Could you elaborate please? I had some ideas but can't really wrap it around my head since it has to be different for each single row

Comment: Can you clarify which CSS layout method you actually use . update your snippet to do so, so it demonstrate was goes wrong and can be used for answering.

Comment: I'll do that in a moment

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't provide the actual code here and recreating it would take quite some time. Thanks everyone for answers, I guess, I'll have to try and fix it myself as it is intended. Cheers guys.

Comment: This doesn't help us understand where the problem is. You don't need to provide an exact copy of your website/app just a working example with HTML, CSS and JS to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have recreated it. https://jsfiddle.net/3m7L0ok6/1/ . My goal is for .shortText and .longText to have a fixed height which is equal to the height of the longest block among them. So all the areas with text would start at the same place

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` together with `align-items: stretch;`:

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  /* this is also the default */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.child {
  width: 50%;
}

.dark {
  background: grey;
}

.light {
  background: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child dark'>foo</div>
  <span class='child light'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</span>
  <div class="child light">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.</div>
  <div class="child dark">bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it would work since it applies globally and it has to be handled for each row separately

Comment: @PCPbiscuit I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Do you want each child in a row to have the same hight according to the highest element in that row?

Comment: @PCPbiscuit I think this is exactly what my example provides.

Comment: let me try it out. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

So you crossed out Flex. So I want to show you another answer I already posted here on stackoverflow.

It is done in jQuery however but I think you get the idea.

```
// Get children
// If it's impossible to give them the same name, you can use a partial selector
var children = $('.child');
var maxHeight = 0;

// Loop all children and check height, if bigger than max then save it
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  if (maxHeight < $(children[i]).outerHeight()) {
    maxHeight = $(children[i]).outerHeight();
  }
}
// Set ALL card bodies to this height
for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
  $(children[i]).height(maxHeight);
}
```

> Original stackoverflow:
> [Equal Height Bootstrap Cards within Slick Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653060/equal-height-bootstrap-cards-within-slick-carousel/54653810#54653810)