# How to make product cards equal height Bootstrap5

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

How to make product cards equal height? Unfortunately, flex is not working.

```
.product-card {
  position: relative;
  padding: 1px;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #fff;
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/keG3p.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equal Height Bootstrap Cards within Slick Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54653060/equal-height-bootstrap-cards-within-slick-carousel)

Comment: I actually like JS solution, but it's not working either. And yes, I've changed var cards = $('.card-body') into var cards = $('.product-card'). Just nothing happens. I add it as <script> block into html.

Comment: You may want to add HTML and whole CSS code to your question so everyone can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Just like @BrunoT says, we can not help you any further if you don't post all your code.

Comment: Full HTML: https://pastebin.com/JFLDpWth
Full CSS: https://pastebin.com/e2VLANf5

Comment: Please only include the code relevant to your question. Keep it minimal and easily reproducible. That means include only a section of HTML and CSS which affects the product cards. Essentially include code related to the given image only

Comment: Okay. I'm not sure, but: HTML: https://pastebin.com/Be6Xhcvh
CSS: https://pastebin.com/NcYDpvX6

Answer (score 1):

Just add **h-100** class on the div where you have added the border class. Check example below.

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="border p-2 h-100">
            <img
              src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_400708cb5f7d44bcb1f272ebc2a51aab~mv2.png"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
              width="100"
            />
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?</p>
            <p>$850.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="border p-2 h-100">
            <img
              src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_400708cb5f7d44bcb1f272ebc2a51aab~mv2.png"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
              width="100"
            />
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
              adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?
            </p>
            <p>$850.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="border p-2 h-100">
            <img
              src="https://static.wixstatic.com/media/2c0034_400708cb5f7d44bcb1f272ebc2a51aab~mv2.png"
              alt=""
              class="img-fluid"
              width="100"
            />
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur,
              adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Pariatur, quod?
            </p>
            <p>$850.00</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. I've created a container for all the cards and each card will have a flex layout with a direction of column. In order for cards being the same height we need to fill the space between the image and the price (description) by using `flex-grow: 1`. See the implementation for more details.

```css
.product-card-container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid green;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.product-card {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 0.4rem;
  row-gap: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.product-card > img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}

.product-info {
  /* Use this for growing an element to 100% width or height inside of a flex container */
  flex-grow: 1
}
```

```html
<div class="product-card-container">

  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5217/5471047557_4dc13f5376_n.jpg">
    <span class="product-info">Short description</span>
    <span><b>$850.00</b></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5217/5471047557_4dc13f5376_n.jpg">
    <span class="product-info">Long long long long long long long long long description</span>
    <span><b>$850.00</b></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5217/5471047557_4dc13f5376_n.jpg">
    <span class="product-info">Very long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long description</span>
    <span><b>$850.00</b></span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="product-card">
    <img src="https://live.staticflickr.com/5217/5471047557_4dc13f5376_n.jpg">
    <span class="product-info">Short description</span>
    <span><b>$850.00</b></span>
  </div>
  
</div>
```